# Is there any tool available to generate ER diagrams based on couchbase buckets

Tags: couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

Is there any tool available to generate ER diagrams based on couchbase buckets
By using model calsses or couchbase GUI also fine

`````
@Document
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class A{

    public static final String PREFIX = "a";
    public static final String ID_DELIMITER = "__";

    @IdPrefix
    private String prefix = PREFIX;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = UNIQUE, delimiter = ID_DELIMITER)
    public String _id;
}````
`````

Comment: Have you seen Hackolade? Or Erwin Data Modeler?